# Multiple first or create in sidekiq creates multiple records instead of updating it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

When a user is created, I am trying to add 1 to the count if a record exists, or create a record with `count: 1` if not.

I have something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :record, on: :create

  def record
    SomeWorker.perform_async(id)
  end
end
```

After a user is created, `SomeWorker` will fire in sidekiq, and will call something like:

```
class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    Record.where(some_conditions).first_or_create()
  end
end
```

It works like charm when I am not using sidekiq and just call it right after a user is created. However, when I seed data that creates 10 users, I expect to create 1 record with `count: 10`, but it creates 10 records with `count: 1`.

Any ideas what is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: It's the classic race condition. Please note that ["Sidekiq is multithreaded so your Workers must be thread-safe."](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#threading). All your workers are running in parallel and none of them initially finds a matching record in `where` and ends up creating the new record with count 1.

Comment: Moreover, Rails docs have a note: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by

Answer (score 1):

It's the classic race condition. Please note that ["Sidekiq is multithreaded so your Workers must be thread-safe."](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#threading). All your workers are running in parallel and none of them initially finds a matching record in `where` and ends up creating the new record with count 1.

I will advice to instead create/find the record beforehand and send it's id for incrementing the `count` value. Though, I'm not sure why you are using Sidekiq to offload a basic `UPDATE` operation.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  after_commit :record, on: :create

  def record
    record = Record.create_with(count: 0).find_by(some_conditions)
    SomeWorker.perform_async(record.id)
  end
end

class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(id)
    Record.find(id).increment!(:count)
  end
end
```

Also, please note that [`increment!`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment!) is not suitable for concurrency either, but it should work in your case.

```
a = Record.first #<Record id: 1, count: 1>
b = Record.first #<Record id: 1, count: 1>
a.increment!(:count) #<Record id: 1, count: 2>
b.increment!(:count) #<Record id: 1, count: 2> ## SHOULD BE 3
b.reload #<Record id: 1, count: 3> It's actually three, but object was stale on update.
```

SQL fires the query below which bumps the value from the last set value.

```
UPDATE `records` SET `count` = COALESCE(`parent_id`, 0) + 1 WHERE `records`.`id` = 1
```